# How to get the name of format/certification by id

Tags: php, database, laravel

So, I have 2 tables in my database : `career_solutions_format` and `career_solutions_certification`, both of them has columns `id` and `category` which is the name of every format/certificate.

Now, `$career_solution->topic_format_id` is equal with column `id`, like 1,3,5. So, I need to display the name of these, from column `category`.

Here is my controller:

```
$data['formatList'] = [''=>'Format'] + \App\Format::lists('category','id')->toArray();
$data['certificationList'] = [''=>'Certification'] + \App\Certification::lists('category','id')->toArray();
```

and here is my view:

```
{!! Form::select('topic_certification_id',$certificationList,null,['required']) !!}
```

How can I make this line to display the name of id, instead of id ?I get the id from table `career_solutions` , column `topic_format_id`, and I need to make a conection between this column and the column `category` from table `career_solutions_format`.

Comment: It should work, pluck I think instead of lists?

Comment: the problem is, I get the id from table `career_solutions ` , column `topic_format_id`, and I need to make a conection between this column and the column `category` from table `career_solutions_format`

Comment: why not create a table relationship between the two tables, and then write a join query to display the name. make sure the table is normalise properly